# Keeping track of dropped indices when dropping elements from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to drop elements from a numpy array `theoretical_price_for_bonds` that do not meet a particular condition. I know I can do this with the line of code below. However, I also want to keep track of the indices of the deleted elements and I was wondering how I could look to do this.

```
theoretical_price_for_bonds = theoretical_price_for_bonds[(theoretical_price_for_bonds>75)]
```

I tried using loops to delete elements dynamically from the numpy array. The prices are okay, but `dropped_indices` turns out to be just a list filled with `None`'s:

```
#To insert values into a list dynamically
class GrowingList(list):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if index >= len(self):
            self.extend([None]*(index + 1 - len(self)))
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)

count = 0
dropped_indices = GrowingList()
for x,value in np.ndenumerate(theoretical_price_for_bonds):
    count = count + 1         
    if count < theoretical_price_for_bonds.shape[0]:
        if theoretical_price_for_bonds[count] < 75:
            theoretical_price_for_bonds = np.delete(theoretical_price_for_bonds, (count), axis=0)
            dropped_indices[count] = count
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep track of the indices of elements that were dropped, just hold on to the boolean mask you use to index into the array and use `np.where`:

```
>>> x = np.array([2,8,3,4,7,6,1])
>>> lix = x > 4
>>> x = x[lix] # this "drops" everything 4 or less
>>> x
array([8, 7, 6])
>>> [dropped] = np.where(~lix) # find the indices that weren't dropped
>>> dropped
array([0, 2, 3, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using a [`pandas.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), which has a `.index` attribute that can be used to keep track of dropped values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(np.array([2,8,3,4,7,6,1]))
print(s.values, s.index)
# (array([2, 8, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1]), Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64'))

s2 = s[s > 4]
print(s2.values, s2.index)
# (array([8, 7, 6]), Int64Index([1, 4, 5], dtype='int64'))
```